# A manga about a demon lord job with a dark-skinned elf woman

Tags: story-identification, manga

I've been trying to find this manga for quite a while now. The manga starts when a guy (probably an otaku) who doesn't have a job sees a job flyer that gives a lot of money. So he goes there and the building has isekai people, like elves and stuff. He finds out that it's a job about being a demon lord something and he has to train. He first trains with a dark-skinned elf lady. And he also meets some demon lord that's acting like a higher up on the company and he gets trained by them.

That's about everything I can remember.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: When you say that she's a black elf, do you mean literally dark-skinned or just evil?

Comment: Was the main character's job to be a demon lord, or was he a regular Japanese salaryman that takes a job for a demon lord?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Starting a Business in Another World!? ~Former Corporate Slave Change Jobs and Advances in a Different World! Building a Labyrinth That Is Impenetrable by the Hero~](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=155528)***...?

From Baka-Updates:

> Former black company employee, Jiro Tanaka leaves his job due to overwork. In his home, he founds a job recruitment template which is from another world company. The job is to test the dungeon created by the demon king. There, the days of diving into the dungeon as a "dungeon tester" were waiting for him to complete the dungeon that even the hero would not be able to clear. He has a hot dark elf boss who has an amazing ability " Magic resistance". The New life of our MC starts!

A frustrated salaryman, Jiro, quits his job and becomes a NEET. He then finds a flyer among his mail, advertising jobs for 'dungeon testers'. He arrives at the building indicated in the flyer, and encounters two receptionists who look like dark-skinned elves. A short time later, a third dark-skinned elf called Suera shows up, and tells Jiro she'll be conducting his interview.

At the start of the interview, the first question Suera asks Jiro is what she looks like. He initially hesitates, afraid to say what he's thinking, and then just comes out and tells her that she looks like a 'dark elf'. To his surprise, she then tells him that he's passed. It turns out that the question was intended to test his 'magical power aptitude'.

The elves were all disguised by concealment spells that make them appear human to anyone with a magical aptitude of level 3 or lower, on a scale of 0-10. Since Jiro could see their true appearance, this proved that his magical aptitude was no lower than level 4. Also, the flyer Jiro received would've appeared blank to anyone who wasn't level 1 or higher, and only people level 2 or higher could've passed through the magical barrier at the building's entrance.

Having unwittingly passed all these tests, Jiro is just the type of candidate this company is looking for. As such, Suera sees fit to tell him more about the job. It turns out that she and the others are part of a Demon King's army in another world, and need candidates like Jiro to test their dungeon, to ensure that Heroes from the other world can't pass through it to reach the Demon King himself.

As part of his preparation for the job, Jiro must undergo various forms of training, with Suera as one of his instructors. She also appears to develop feelings for him over the course of the story.

[image]

[image]